# what it shows specific protocol on wireshark?

Tags: protocols, wireshark

when sniffing on wireshark I have noticed that for most of the packets it captures, it shows the third layer protocol... why does it show the protocol of this specific layer and no other?
here is a screenshot of wireshark protocol:

[image]

thanks y'all

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a network protocol analyzer. You can get information about all layers. Refer to the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSE_r6aYfu4